# Easy Way to Adjust Parameter Ranges in Latin HyperCube Sampling

Tags: python, simulation, physics, sampling

I have generated a random set of 6 parameters with 50,000 samples each, which I am using as 50,000 cavity configurations for a physics project. After using these 6 parameters in a neural network, I isolated the 1% of configurations that deviated the most from the expected results.

The resulting "Worst 1%" parameter distributions have different shapes for each of the 6 parameters. I would like to rerun the process, but sample more heavily in the error prone areas. Is there an easy way to make this adjustment in Python? Currently, I can only sample from 0 to 1.

For example, the parameter called Dielectric Resonator needs to range from 1 to 45, with sampling that varies as according to the function 1.97372 E^(0.118317 (-11.4466 + x)). Picture is linked below. Update: Apparently I can't post pictures because this is my first question on Stack Exchange, hopefully this link appears now [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OfYR.png

How can I make this adjustment? Is it possible to make this change for other functions such as Gaussian distributions, or a piecewise function?

This is the code I am currently using to sample:

```
import numpy as np 
from smt.sampling_methods import LHS
limits = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0,1.0], [0.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0]])
sampling = LHS(xlimits=limits,criterion='maximin')
```

Comment: Good question, adding an example that folks can reproduce will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Adding the picture you promised would help.